# fusionpbx change extensions password

Tags: postgresql, freeswitch, fusionpbx

how to change extension password directly from PostgreSQL ?

I know the extenstions stored in "v_extensions" , So I created 100 ext from there and all working .

but when I change the password for any extension from PostgreSQL , the softphone tell me about "wrong password" .

**I used this for update the extension password in "v_extensions" table in PostgreSQL .**

```
UPDATE "v_extensions" SET
"extension_uuid" = '8b4e9977-55a3-4b2f-b19e-5c6290265000',
"domain_uuid" = '795df1b6-e28d-4a00-9650-02bbb8f6bc17',
"extension" = '5000',
"number_alias" = NULL,
"password" = '1234567',
"accountcode" = NULL,
"effective_caller_id_name" = NULL,
"effective_caller_id_number" = NULL,
"outbound_caller_id_name" = NULL,
"outbound_caller_id_number" = NULL,
"emergency_caller_id_name" = NULL,
"emergency_caller_id_number" = NULL,
"directory_first_name" = NULL,
"directory_last_name" = NULL,
"directory_visible" = 'true',
"directory_exten_visible" = 'true',
"limit_max" = '5',
"limit_destination" = 'error/user_busy',
"missed_call_app" = NULL,
"missed_call_data" = NULL,
"user_context" = '165.232.75.8',
"toll_allow" = NULL,
"call_timeout" = '30',
"call_group" = NULL,
"call_screen_enabled" = 'false',
"user_record" = NULL,
"hold_music" = NULL,
"auth_acl" = NULL,
"cidr" = NULL,
"sip_force_contact" = NULL,
"nibble_account" = NULL,
"sip_force_expires" = NULL,
"mwi_account" = NULL,
"sip_bypass_media" = NULL,
"unique_id" = NULL,
"dial_string" = NULL,
"dial_user" = NULL,
"dial_domain" = NULL,
"do_not_disturb" = NULL,
"forward_all_destination" = NULL,
"forward_all_enabled" = NULL,
"forward_busy_destination" = NULL,
"forward_busy_enabled" = NULL,
"forward_no_answer_destination" = NULL,
"forward_no_answer_enabled" = NULL,
"forward_user_not_registered_destination" = NULL,
"forward_user_not_registered_enabled" = NULL,
"follow_me_uuid" = NULL,
"forward_caller_id_uuid" = NULL,
"follow_me_enabled" = NULL,
"follow_me_destinations" = NULL,
"enabled" = 'true',
"description" = NULL,
"absolute_codec_string" = NULL,
"force_ping" = NULL
WHERE "extension_uuid" = '8b4e9977-55a3-4b2f-b19e-5c6290265000';
```

when I use the fusionpbx web GUI , the changes is done without problems , is there other places chould I have to look when I change the password other then this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason

the data cached in memecached , that should be flushed after any change